# Assigning values dynamically from a groovy config file

Tags: groovy

As I am reading values from a file in my Groovy code, I want to assign these values to the equivalent properties in my object as i am iterating through the map values!

**code:**

```
new ConfigSlurper().parse(new File(configManager.config.myFile.filepath)
                   .toURI().toURL()).each { k,v -> 
    if (k == 'something') {
        v.each {
            myObject.$it =v.$it 
            // so here i want this dynamic assignment to occur 
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: finding a key with a string comparsion in an `each` loop of a map is rather wasteful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code there would already work like this, if you would use the form:

```
myObject."$it.key" = it.value
```

Here is a slightly more protective version:

```
class MyObject {
    Long x,y
}

def obj = new MyObject()

def cfg = new ConfigSlurper().parse('''\
a { 
    x = 42
    y = 666
}
b {
    x = 93
    y = 23
}''')

cfg.b.findAll{ obj.hasProperty(it.key) }.each{
    obj.setProperty(it.key,it.value)
}

assert obj.x==93 && obj.y==23
```

Comment: This is awesome and much better ! Thanks